# No funciona npm install y he intentado de todo

Tags: javascript, nodejs, npm, paquetes-npm

tengo un problemón con NodeJS y es que no funciona npm install de ninguna forma, he intentado de todo, he buscado en StackOverflow y YouTube pero nada me funciona, he intentado incluso desactivando el cortafuegos que uso (TinyWall) e incluso restaurando a un punto de restauración anterior de Windows y nada, instalé incluso una versión anterior (la 18) y sigo obteniendo este problema:

```
npm info using npm@9.3.1
npm info using node@v18.14.0
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
```

Y al intentar instalar se traba aquí:

```
   idealTree:node: sill idealTree buildDeps
```

Quiero decir que no soy un novato, hace tiempo usé node y nunca tuve estos problemas. He intentado con proxy, sin proxy, desinstalar node, borrar archivos de node, de todo y nada, por favor, si alguien me puede dar ideas de cómo solucionarlo lo agradezco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

al fin logré dar con la solución, resulta ser que los paquetes de node están bloqueados para Cuba (me parece que antes no era así) y resulta ser que Node no usa la configuración del proxy de windows por defecto y por eso no había manera de que instalase usando proxy o no, entonces tuve que establecer manualmente el proxy en node para que acceda a la VPN del movil a la que está anclada mi PC